# Scanner not reading the last line

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I have this piece of code and my problem is that the Scanner is not picking up the last line unless I hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

I have already tried all answers available but had no luck. I can not use `BufferedReader`, I have to do this using `Scanner` only.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int noOfCases = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();                  //consuming the left out \n
for (int i = 1; i <= noOfCases; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String arr[] = line.split(" ");
    int white = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
    int red = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
    int green = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);

    if (white > 0 && red > 0 && green > 0) {
        count = count + (white / 3) + (red / 3) + (green / 3);
        white = white - ((white / 3) * 3);
        red = red - ((red / 3) * 3);
        green = green - ((green / 3) * 3);
    }
    int minVal = Math.min(Math.min(white, red), green);
    count = count + minVal;

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

The above code is not reading the last line, passing the input is not in my hands.

The sample input is like (no. of test cases followed by the test cases):

```
3        // no of test cases
5 5 5
10 4 2
4 4 4
```

Comment: How about copying a newline character and pasting it to your console?

Comment: @MikeCAT passing the input is not in my hands, have to make it work by making changes in the code only

Comment: How do you think the terminal will distinguish `4 4 4` from `4 4 40` or `4 4 4 4` without reading newline character?

Comment: Do "the code" in "making changes in the code only" include the code to pass the input, if any?

Comment: @MikeCAT I know the concern but is there any way by which this could be done making some changes in the code?

Comment: @MikeCAT We can tweak the code in any possible way, but the input pattern is predefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110748/discussion-between-abhishek-and-mikecat).

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons last line is not defined unless you press enter which helps building scanner. `nextInt()` may be sufficient.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int noOfCases=scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();                  //consuming the left out \n
    for(int i=1;i<=noOfCases;i++)
    {
    int count=0;
    int white=scanner.nextInt();
    int red=scanner.nextInt();
    int green=scanner.nextInt();

    if(white>0&&red>0&&green>0)
    {
        count=count+(white/3)+(red/3)+(green/3);
        white=white-((white/3)*3);
        red=red-((red/3)*3);
        green=green-((green/3)*3);
    }
    int minVal=Math.min(Math.min(white,red),green);
    count=count+minVal;

    System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why you have three `int white=scanner.nextInt();` instead of reading for `white`, `red` and `green`?

Comment: Lines are defined by line terminators. There is no 'for some reason"' about it.